# "В надежде на лучшие возможности" — отсутствие знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Перспективы... получить хорошую работу были ничтожны, а та, что у него была, его не устраивала. Поэтому **в надежде на лучшие возможности** он принял решение перевезти сюда семью.*

Очень хочется выделить запятыми (или тире) **указанную** часть предложения. И очень хочется понять: **почему их нет**? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто нет причин для обособления. Почему нет - как правило, объяснять не надо. Объяснять надо, почему есть.

Answer (score 2):

Можно было бы выделить, будь оборот подлиннее, да и то, если автор будет сильно настаивать. 
А так этот оборот не является ни источником информации, ни распространенным, ни каким другим, требующим обособления. То есть единственный мотив - интонационный, но коротковато для такого.

А вот тире - да, возможно, именно как интонационный знак. Но, конечно, ни в коем случае не обязательный тут.

Answer (score 2):

Обособление оборота **факультативно**, поэтому для принятия решения требуется дополнительный анализ.

Вариант с обособлением: Поэтому, **в надежде на лучшие возможности**, он принял решение перевезти сюда семью.

1) Хотя в тексте нет обособления, **постановка запятых здесь является оправданной и в интонационном, и в семантическом плане**.

Обстоятельственный оборот достаточно распространен, обозначает причину основного действия, которую можно подчеркнуть обособлением, тем более что оборот стоит после наречия со значением следствия (встреча двух обстоятельств с разным значением в начале предложения).

2) **Можно ли не выделять оборот?** К примеру, автор не хочет этого делать, но тогда, при наличии двух обстоятельств в начале предложения, надо проверить их интонационную сочетаемость (могут ли они образовать одну произносительную фразу).

И вот в данном случае это не очень получается: язык "спотыкается", хочется сделать паузу и обособить оборот. Чтобы не обособлять второе обстоятельство, можно уменьшить его объём или объём первого обстоятельства, то есть интонационно их состыковать.

**Примеры без обособления:**

Тогда в надежде на лучшие возможности он принял решение перевезти сюда семью.

Поэтому в надежде на разъяснение повторю свой вопрос

Comment: >>* постановка запятых здесь является оправданной и в интонационном, и в семантическом плане.* А в синтаксическом (самом главном) плане – нет. А интонацией можно играть, как бог на душу положит.

Comment: О, не заметил... У вас пример с одной запятой?! А перед ним – попытка объяснить? Конечно, пардон, но это уж вовсе безграмотно.

Comment: Не приходите в восторг, @ Niemand, это всего лишь  неточность (запятая не нужна).  И примера никакого  нет,  я просто переделываю имеющееся предложение. К сожалению, Вы не различаете два плана интонации: объективный и субъективный. Объективный план - это паузы, восходящий/нисходящий тон, темп речи, а субъективный - пометки  "с воодушевлением и др." И еще информация лично для Вас: три принципа пунктуации (семантический, грамматический и интонационный) едины. Грамматический и интонационный - это форма речи, а семантический - ее содержание,  и ведущим скорее можно назвать смысл, а не форму.

Comment: Не надо мудрствовать! То, о чем вы говорите, в лучшем случае имеет отношение к "авторской пунктуации". Не надо ее выпячивать. Сначала школьная грамматика, потом всяческие мудрености. А у вас наоборот.

Comment: А это что, форум  для школьников? Кстати, Вы не могли бы дать ссылку на информацию, которую Вы излагаете в своем ответе?  И я согласна с @Morkovkin, на вопрос Вы не ответили, зато порадовали нам комментариями.

Comment: Умудренные житейским опытом тоже могут задавать школьные вопросы. ) Разумеется, ответ г-на @Morkovkin вам понравился больше. "Оборот, являющийся источником информации". Но он модератор! )) Интересно, а вот на "мама мыла раму" тоже нужен источник? Почему нет запятой?!

Comment: @Niemand   Можно, я поучаствую?..  Ну и ладно, пусть мой вопрос будет т.н. школьным,  не в этом суть.  Но ведь интонация - вещь очень тонкая.  "Мама, мыла раму?" - и уже нужно отвечать школьнику,  уже нужен источник.

Comment: @Римма Михайловна, Вы совершенно правы, я примерно то же самое хотела сказать, но потом решила рассмотреть другую сторону вопроса.

Comment: @ Niemand, Вопросы бывают разными, но в нашем случае мы имеем не  школьный вопрос, на который Вы пытались дать школьный ответ. Нет причин для обособления? Тогда укажите причины обособления обстоятельств, выраженных падежными формами,  и докажите, что эти причины отсутствуют. Желательно рассмотреть вопросы, связанные с позицией оборота, его распространенностью и коммуникативной значимостью. Ничего этого нет в Вашем ответе.

Comment: @Sibylla, то есть, как сказала Римма Михайлова, *"Мама, мыла раму?" - и уже нужно отвечать школьнику, уже нужен источник.* И вы тоже с этим согласны? Видите, как человек трактует "интонацию"? Это ведь в том числе и с вашей легкой руки. Интонация - вещь в грамматике самая распоследняя, ею надо заниматься на филфаках, да не на первых курсах. Иначе будет "мама, мыла раму" - а что, интонация такая...

Comment: Жаль, что с Вами не посоветовались, как и когда надо изучать интонацию.  Но не это главное, где же ответ на мой вопрос? Объясните, почему отсутствуют причины для обособления, что же Вас несколько раз надо просить. Кстати, в учебнике по синтаксису написано, что интонация является основным средством связи в БСП, какая же она распоследняя?

Comment: @Sibylla Коли уж вы меня упомяни, уточню. Я не считаю ответ  Niemand "неответом". Это именно ответ, даже ответ правильный, но только формально, лишенный практического наполнения. То, что в пунктуации существует этакая презумпция отсутствия известно всем, да, правила формулируются на случаи использования знаков, а не на случаи неупотребления. Но если вопрос задан, ясно, что человек хочет получить несколько больше этой очевидной информации, вспомнить какие-то правила на подобные случаи и уяснить, чем конкретно пример отличается от этих случаев.

Comment: А короткие всегда ответы всегда попадают на проверку сообществу. При проверке и и выбрал более или менее подходящий вариант, такой ответ лучше давать в комментариях, хотя формально он логически правильный, но практически малозначимый.

Comment: Morkovkin : *Это именно ответ, даже ответ правильный, но только формально, лишенный практического наполнения*. Тогда уж не практического, а теоретического наполнения, г-н @Morkovkin. ))

Comment: @Niemand Именно практического. Давайте-ка всё-таки хоть такие термины не переопределять в угоду Вашей левой ноге. Вы ответили в стиле Капитана Очевидности: ***теоретически*** правильно, но ***практически*** бессодержательно. Кстати, забавно, я Вас технарем считал, а Вы теорию с практикой путаете,))) Где такому учат?

Comment: @Morkovkin, я ответил практически (запятые не нужны, и это правильный ответ), но не стал растекаться мыслию по древу (привлекать высокоумную теорию, которая здесь не нужна). Практически нам что важно? -- правильно, нам важно, нужен знак или нет. Так что всё-таки давайте-ка не будем...

Comment: *я ответил практически (запятые не нужны, и это правильный ответ)* - это ***практически несостоятельный*** ответ, ибо человеку нет от того некакой пользы.  А ***правильным*** он только ***теоретически***. Разберитесь наконец в элементарных терминах.

Comment: Нет пользы... Человек думал-думал, голову ломал: нужно - не нужно... Задал вопрос, и сразу ответили, и правильно ответили. Ура или не ура? А вы - "нет пользы". Термины - они такие термины...

Answer (score 0):

Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей с предлогами, обособляются для попутного пояснения или смыслового выделения. Такое обособление факультативно:

Такое обособление факультативно:

>

- Осталась только серебристая пыль.
  Но, когда девки, по глупости,    через несколько дней стерли ее, с
  тетей Тоней сделалась истерика    (Бун.);
- Филин, с шорохом, задевая крыльями солому, срывался с    крыши
  (Бун.);
- И Наташка, с болезненным удивлением, глядела на    разряженный народ 
  (Бун.);
- В полной тьме, среди ночи, подвезли    Медею к железнодорожному
  вокзалу (Улиц.);
- Ночью, против окрепшего    ветра, отряд шел в порт на посадку
  (Плат.);
- За одиннадцать лет, при    ежедневной езде, наверно,было пережито
  немало интересных приключений    (Ч.). [(См. о возможности постановки тире § 76.)](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg76.php)

[См.:  Д.Э.Розенталь Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)

Comment: Здесь нет пояснительного значения, примере это обстоятельство (оборот) цели. Поясняющие обстоятельства могут быть изъяты из предложения без ущерба для основного смысла. У нас - обстоятельство цели/причины. Обособление возможно, но исключительно из стилистических соображений. При слабой распространенности оборота и самого предложения смысла в таком обособлении нет.

Comment: Morkovkin, речь идет лишь о факультативном обособлении. Играет роль не только пояснительное значение, но и ряд других причин: степень распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д.

Comment: Если автор, например, желает интонационно выделить этот оборот, обособление вполне возможно.

Comment: У меня речь идет том, что рекомендация у Р. применяется ***для попутного пояснения или смыслового выделения***. В рассматриваемом примере этого нет. Обособление, да, возможно, но только по другим причинам, причем здесь скорее нежелательно.

Comment: *Если автор, например, желает интонационно выделить этот оборот, обособление вполне возможно* - это я, простите, и без вас знаю.

Comment: Я рад, что вы знаете. Решение о выделение в смысловом плане принимает сам автор текста, если в предложении это возможно. Здесь это возможно.  Sibylla подробно объяснила.

Comment: Серж, я и это знаю, кто там что принимает. Если можете ответьте мне  по сути. Если нет, простите. Мне не интересны ваши рассуждения на отвлеченные темы. Мое мнение Вам понятно? *Здесь нет пояснительного значения* - это у Розенталя есть, все примеры на этот случай (кроме, может первого у Бунина - но очень сомнительно). ***Тут нельзя применять эту рекомендацию***.

Comment: Послушайте, вы сами себе противоречите. Вы сами пишите: ***смыслового выделения***.  Т. е. помимо пояснительного значения, есть и смысловое выделение.  Пояснительное значение - одна из причин.  Есть ряд и других причин.

Comment: Оборот может быть выделен в смысловом плане, почему -  Sibylla объяснила.